# The PeriodCustomer column is not found or cannot be used in this expression. Power BI (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am writing code to determine the Running Total Customers: All Customers Until This Period. Now, I have created a This period's Customers table to contain the following code:

`PeriodeKlant = DISTINCTCOUNT(Text[PCHN])`

I have now created the code as below:

```
Running Total Customers = 
var _currdate=MAX(Tekst[Datum].[Date])
var _salesthisperiod=Tekst[Verkoopdoc]
return
if(_salesthisperiod>0,
    CALCULATE(
        [PeriodeKlant], 
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED(Tekst[Datum].[Date]),
            ISONORAFTER(Tekst[Datum].[Date], _currdate, DESC)
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

I get the message that the previously created column cannot be used, this column has the value integer and at summary it says sum. I don't know if that is why I would not be able to load this data?

But because of this error I can't run my measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your DAX is written, it's expecting `[PeriodeKlant]` to be a measure rather than a calculated column. Try deleting this calculating this column and defining it as a measure instead.